# ¿Como copilar y ejecutar un archivo java con bibliotecas externas, sin usar un entorno de desarrollo integrado?

Tags: java, cmd, ide, javac

Muy buenas,
con fines educativos y de conocer realmente como funciona, me gustaría saber como copilar y ejecutar un archivo **.java** con bibliotecas externas asociadas , ya que simplemente con los comandos **javac** y **java** no es posible. Tengo entendido que hay que poner nuestras bibliotecas **.jar** en nuestra classpath, el problema es que desconozco como hacer esto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: mete todos los archivos compilados (incluyendo los de las librerias) dentro de un zip con extension .jar

Comment: `java -cp path1:path2:. lemainclas` o `java -cp path1;path2;path3 lalalaClas`

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolver mi problema, a continuación le explico como realizar lo que requería:

Imaginemos que tenemos la siguiente estructura con los siguientes directorios y archivos:

```
C:\Documentos\Proyecto-Java
                 |
                 |--> bibliotecas
                 |         |-->biblioteca.jar
                 |
                 |--> Main.java
```

Por obvias razones podemos suponer que el archivo **"Main.java"** hace uso de la biblioteca **"biblioteca.jar"**, entonces, lo primero que debemos hacer es ubicarnos en el directorio donde se encuentra nuestro proyecto, en nuestro caso seria el directorio **"Proyecto-Java"**, y deberemos escribir los siguientes comandos:

```
Primer comando: javac -classpath C:\Documentos\Proyecto-Java;bibliotecas\biblioteca.jar Main.java
Segundo comando: java -classpath C:\Documentos\Proyecto-Java;bibliotecas\biblioteca.jar Main
```